# How can I convert image buffer to string base64?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox-gl-js, filepond, mapbox-marker

[image]I am uploading image using Filepond library to MongoDB using Mongoose. I want to show the image in the map's marker using pop-up feature. Image I am getting back in the format

```
{ location:
   { type: 'Point',
     coordinates: [ -86.34164, 39.81514 ],
     formattedAddress: 'Lucas Oil Raceway, Brownsburg, IN 46234, US' },
  _id: 5f10a1867435d3f048a14acc,
  storeId: '009',
  dateCompleted: 2020-07-01T04:00:00.000Z,
  description:
   ' setup datguard. backups, flashack logs  and monitoring',
  createdAt: 2020-07-16T18:50:46.997Z,
  storeImage:
   Binary {
     _bsontype: 'Binary',
     sub_type: 0,
     position: 3569671,
     buffer:
      <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a....
storeImageType: 'image/jpeg',
  __v: 0 }
```

I am able to show rest of the properties except image. Is there a way i can convert this image buffer to string and then set to map properties.

```
stores = data.data.map(store => {
        return {
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [
                    store.location.coordinates[0],
                    store.location.coordinates[1]
                ]
            },
            properties: {
                storeId: store.storeId,
                dateCompleted: store.dateCompleted,
                description: store.description,
                         
          image:`data:${store.storeImageType};charset=utf-8;base64,${store.storeImage.data.toString('base64')}`,
```

##with this i see image content as "data:image/jpeg;charset=utf;base64,233,4444,555,67
icon: 'shop'
}
};
});

```
function setMarkers(stores) {
    //add markers to the map
    stores.forEach(function (marker) {

        // create a HTML element for each feature
        var el = document.createElement('div-marker');
        el.className = 'marker';

        // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
        var mkr = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
                    offset: 25
                }) // add popups this is where i need to set image
                .setHTML("<img src='" + marker.properties.image + "' width='160' />"))
            .addTo(map);
        mkrs.push(mkr);
    });
}
```

All this code is in public javascript folder using NodeJS Express.

Answer (score 3):

From the format you posted, it seems like the image buffer is located in `store.storeImage.buffer`. `storeImage.data` must be a getter that is converting it to something else - from the looks of it, probably an array?

Try using `store.storeImage.buffer.toString('base64')` - passing `'base64'` to `toString` is a feature of buffers specifically, other types don't handle it the same.

Edit: Apparently `store.storeImage` itself is the buffer. So you should use simply `store.storeImage.toString('base64')`

Edit: Apparently it describes itself as a buffer despite not actually offering a node.js Buffer object. I suggest converting the array to a buffer and then encoding as base64: `Buffer.from(store.storeImage.data).toString('base64')`

Comment: using above code I am getting error ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined``` Looks like it doesnt like buffer. When I debug store.storeImage property type is buffer and data is array.

Comment: Also added picture to my question. Shows the store object

Comment: ```map.js:31 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at map.js:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,[object Object]:1 GET data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,[object Object] net::ERR_INVALID_URL``` before object were converted to array. Not using storeImage.data.toString('base64') is returning [object Object]

Comment: @user557657 odd. Try my edit now. I'd have thought an object describing itself as a buffer would, yknow, provide a buffer somewhere, not just an array...

Comment: This code is in js file which is in public folder. I am not sure how to use buffer on browser side.

Comment: @user557657 Ah, I saw in your question that you were using nodejs Express so I thought that's where that code was. Would it not be simpler to convert to base64 on server side and send that to browser?

Comment: Yes I will do that. Let you know soon if that works. Thanks a lot!!\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218469/discussion-between-user557657-and-klaycon).

Comment: @user557657 Apologies, stack chat is blocked on my network.

Comment: I added this code function convertBufferToString(stores) {
stores.forEach(
(store) =>
(store.storeImage = Buffer.from(store.storeImage.toString("base64")))
);
return stores;
}
now on browser it still look same.

Comment: @user557657 You're calling the `toString` on `store.storeImage` and then calling `Buffer.from` on the result. Move a closing parenthesis further in so you have `Buffer.from(store.storeImage)`

Comment: same result. I am sure there is something very minor issue but cant seem to find it. This is what i have now - ```Buffer.from(store.storeImage).toString("base64"))```

Comment: Only time it looks promising when I use ```store.storeImage.toString("base64")`` Result lookslike this ```"/9j/aAAAQScdfghfjgscf........"

Comment: @user557657 That looks like base64. Have you tried sending that to the browser and prefixing it with the correct `data` tag?

Comment: tried prefix like this -``` `data:${store.storeImageType};charset=utf-8;base64,${store.storeImage.toString("base64")}`) ``` but in browser it always show as type buffer.

Comment: Your solution really helped me, i have been on this buffer issue for a week now.